# Mysql multiple LIKE not working

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like, autosuggest

I have a stores table. Some fields are name,website,description,etc.

I have an autosuggest search bar. I want to match input and display some related stores. Right now it works perfectly matching user input with a LIKE statement for name.

```
$input = $_GET["q"];
$data = array();
// query your DataBase here looking for a match to $input
include_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name,linklabel,permalink FROM tblMerchants WHERE name LIKE '%$input%'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $json = array();
    $json['name'] = ucwords($row['linklabel']);
    $json['value'] = $row['permalink'];
    $data[] = $json;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

However, I'm trying to match user input with multiple fields in the table. I'm trying the following and it isn't working:

```
SELECT linklabel,permalink
FROM tblMerchants
WHERE name LIKE '%$input%'
 OR website LIKE '%$input%'
 OR description LIKE '%$input%'
```

Trying to figure this out. Any input is appreciated!

Sorry, should have mentioned this. By not working I mean that when using the multiple LIKE statement its still only returning results that are like 'name'

Comment: By not working do you mean you're getting an error or just no results?

Comment: tip: I don't know if this is your production code or just an example, but remember to sanitize your input before using it in a query. Your code is vulnerable to sql-injections. You could use mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that. By not working I mean that when using the multiple LIKE statement its still only returning results that are like 'name'

Comment: Does the query actually return anything for cases where you use a different field other than `name`? I mean, just using one like for `website`, for example. Try and clarify what do you mean by `it isn't working`.

Comment: Ok seems like when I'm matching a one word query to a one word field Its working. But as soon as I try to match a one word query with a multiple word field such as description it isn't working. Also, when I try to match a two word query with a two word field that I know exists, it doesn't show any results either. Could it be a problem with the database types for these fields? Or perhaps the collation. They are varchar and text. The collation is latin1_swedish_ci. Also, when I try to use mysql_real_escape_string() on the query string I get no results in the search??

Maybe I should try FULLTEXT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`like`s and `and`s are notorius in not playing well with each others.

Use parentherses to clarify, e.g.

```
SELECT linklabel,permalink 
FROM tblMerchants WHERE 
(name LIKE '%$input%') OR 
(website LIKE '%$input%')  OR 
(description LIKE '%$input%')
```

Otherwise it can be trying to guess and do things like

```
SELECT linklabel,permalink 
FROM tblMerchants WHERE 
name LIKE ('%$input%' OR 
website LIKE '%$input%')  OR 
(description LIKE '%$input%')
```

I don't don;t if the above is an actual query that it would try, but basically the way it would combine/chain them could be 'undefined' and subject to interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine (well, except for the SQL injection danger and that fact that it will grow slow quickly).  Please show sample data containing rows that you think should be returned but are not when you execute this query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"SELECT linklabel, permalink FROM tblMerchants WHERE
name like '%$input%'
UNION SELECT linklabel, permalink FROM tblMerchants WHERE
description like '%$input%'
UNION SELECT linklabel, permalink FROM tblMerchants WHERE
website like '%$input%'";
```

It should work.